# Create my own AccessTokens with MS Identity Platform

Tags: jwt, access-token, microsoft-identity-platform

I am in the process of expanding our login options on our product to support MS Identity Platform, to be able to use Azure AD login (and gain SSO/MFA with that)
Currently we are using .Net Core + JWT (JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
The environment is angular clients, .Net Core APA, and a back-end database.

I have the setup working.

My challenge is that in our business model and backend database we have ~2.000 userrights and our own User/Role model granting access.

I am currently getting the IdToken from MSAL and in my proof of concept using the oid to couple the Azure ID with our User model.

But, in our existing JWT solution, our access token holds claims about the User Id, but also the role, and another property (Unit/Vessel) determining access. From these three properties we can verify against the 2.000 userights on API side whether or not a request is allowed or not.

I would like to keep this information (User, Role, Unit) in the token - but have doubts on how.

Constraints:

- We cant create/use Azure claims. We have too many, and customers will manage the Azure application - while we create, add, remove rights for each version of our software.
- Azure don't know about role/unit data - and these are different for each customer - so that information can't be in Azure either.

My best idea is outlined below - would this approach be correct, and live up to the way ID/Access is separated?

I hope someone can give me some feedback on this.

My idea is, that the Angular client gets the Azure IDToken. I then use the Azure IDToken, call our API, which on server side, validates ID Token, and then grants me an access token, which contains the user, role and unit. This token is not Azure'd at all, just a token generated by our API - which again will be the only one validating it). Pro's on this approach is also I can keep one type of Access Token, no matter which IDToken is supplied by Azure or our own API.

Tried to outline the flow below in this DrawIO diagram.
[image: Azure/API Auth flow]

I hope someone with more experience in the Token field can validate if this would be a viable approach?

Best regards
/Anders

Answer (score 1):

This is a viable approach except for one thing.
*Do not use Id token for authorization.*

Your front-end should acquire an *access token* from AAD for your back-end.
This access token contains the user objectId, allowing you to map the user to a user in your database.

An Id token is only meant for the application that requested authentication and tells it metadata on the user like their display name etc., but it is not meant for authorizing anything.

Comment: First lines in documentation says 'ID Tokens should be used to validate that a user is who they claim to be'.( https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#using-the-id_token )That must be the Authentication part. So from that using the IDToken to validate identity should be fine - right? 
Access Tokens are for validating authorization (access) - and there I would create my own access tokens. 
I have no need to get an Access Token from Azure - since I don't need to access anyting there - i just need to know who the user is.